# Using a Nokia HERE map within CartoDB

Tags: carto, here-maps, nokia

I currently am developing a map that uses the following code to set the map background:

```js
//set the map background
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'http://www.thunderforest.com/'
}).addTo(map);
```

I have signed up for a Nokia HERE account so that I can use their [transit map](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1243560/eb1883f3efefda3cb20e9db14ea7c550). I have an APP ID and APP CODE.

According to their [instructions](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/map-types.html), (which I have also included below), I need to do a few steps before I can use their maps.

Can someone help me translate their steps into the what I need to do?

```js
// Create a Platform object (one per application):
var platform = new H.service.Platform({ 'app_id': '{YOUR_APP_ID}',
    'app_code': '{YOUR_APP_CODE}' });

// Get an object containing the default map layers:
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Instantiate the map using the normal map as the base layer:
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer',
  defaultLayers.normal.map);

// Change the map base layer to the satellite map with traffic information:
map.setBaseLayer(defaultLayers.satellite.traffic);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the L.tileLayer with CartoDB.js/Leaflet map object, just switch it's url param to a Nokia xyz url. Nokia has examples here including Transit Day, notice that your app id & code are appended to the url: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/examples-base.html

Comment: In the example listed, they provide the following code: https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day.transit/13/4152/2818/256/png8
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}. As far as I understand, this is for a single tile. How do I modify this code to request the entire map?

Comment: You could use the following:
https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day.transit/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}

Comment: try this with your APPID https://1.traffic.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/flowtile/newest/normal.day/15/16358/10898/256/png8?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write the parameters of the URL without `{}`, something like:

`?app_id=JPRO.....iUY&app_code=PdZ.....x-og`

Also, sharing your credentials here is not a very safe practice :)

In any case, the following works loading a CartoDB basemap and overlying a Nokia transit layer:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
  }).addTo(map,0);

L.tileLayer('https://1.traffic.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/flowtile/newest/normal.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png8?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg', 
    {}).addTo(map,1);
```